# How do I support 16:9 Android apps to fit into 18:9 aspect ratio Android device?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have 16:9 Android apps. It's not fitting into 18:9 aspect ratio Android device like Samsung Galaxy Note 8,LG V30,Huawei Honor 9i,Google Pixel 2 XL,OnePlus 5T,Oppo F5. So please help me to find any solution. I tried

```
<meta-data android:name="android.max_aspect" android:value="2.1" />
```

and `android:resizeableActivity="false"` It's notworking in my app.

Comment: Which layout are you using

Comment: Relative layout I am using.

Comment: You can read this. It will give you some idea..https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html. You may have to re-work your design part to support all screen sizes.

Comment: I tried using ConstraintLayout like this but still it's not giving same output for same rang of device like 6 inch.

<RelativeLayout android:background="@drawable/india_world_bg"
    android:id="@+id/programMainBg"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="16:9"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">